# Visual Basic - Displaying a combo box entry over a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

to keep it short and simple, I am attempting to display a number selected through a combo box on a second form through a label.

Here are the bits that are relevant to the issue I am having:

```
for i = 1 To 31
cmb_days.Items.Add(i) 
next
' Populating combo box 
days = cmb_days.text
frm_result.lbl_renting = "Renting for " & days & " Days"
```

I have tried using other variants such as cmb_days.selecteditem to no avail

I am also kinda having issues with like telling my code to do things with whatever number is actually selected in the combo box, idk I am veryyyyy new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks more or less correct.. But the question is where your call to update the label occurs in your code...

This is a minimal working example, with just a ComboBox on a form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 31
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Me.Text = ComboBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

The update of the label (in this case the text of the form, but it works exactly the same with a label on a different form) occurs in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of ComboBox1.

If you copied your code straight from the project, you haven't had time to select anything yet, so the `Text` property will be empty.

Comment: Thank you Magnus, I realised I am incredibly stupid and forgot to add .text onto the end of "frm_result.lbl_renting". I have spent hours looking at my code and scouring the internet for solutions, I feel silly now!

Comment: I'm used to only see two levels of properties, so I didn't even notice that.. :)